# Verifying the winner of a tic tac toe game. Filling a matrix from user input string arrays

Tags: c#, matrix

I have to find the winner of a 3x3 TicTacToe game. Firstly I user input N (number of moves) and then N moves like: (1 0),(0 2) etc. (X starts the game). The program needs to return the winner "X" or "0", or return "Draw" if there is not a winner. For example for the following input:

- 7
- 1 1
- 2 1
- 2 0
- 0 2
- 1 0
- 1 2
- 0 0

The output is : X

I wrote the following code, but I have problem at inputing the moves and calling the method.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp20
{
   class Program
    {
        public static string Tictactoe(int[][] moves)
        {
            int[] rowsValues = new int[3];
            int[] columnsValues = new int[3];
            int diagonalSum = 0;
            int antiDiagonalSum = 0;
            const int c1 = 3;
            int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            bool isFirstPlayer = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                int rowIndex = moves[i][0];
                int columnIndex = moves[i][1];
                int value = isFirstPlayer ? 1 : -1;
                if (rowIndex == columnIndex)
                {
                    diagonalSum += value;
                }

                if (columnIndex == c1 - rowIndex - 1)
                {
                    antiDiagonalSum += value;
                }

                rowsValues[rowIndex] += value;
                columnsValues[columnIndex] += value;
                if (Math.Abs(diagonalSum) == c1 ||
                   Math.Abs(antiDiagonalSum) == c1 ||
                   Math.Abs(rowsValues[rowIndex]) == c1 ||
                   Math.Abs(columnsValues[columnIndex]) == c1)
                {
                    return isFirstPlayer ? "X" : "0";
                }

                isFirstPlayer = !isFirstPlayer;
            }

            return "Draw";
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp20
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] rowsValues = new int[3];
            int[] columnsValues = new int[3];
            const int c1 = 3;
            int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            for (int i = n; n > 0; n--)
            {
                string[] moves = Console.ReadLine().Split();
                int a = int.Parse(moves[0]);
                int b = int.Parse(moves[1]);
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I further fill a 3x3 matrix from the values that I user inputed as strings arrays? First number representing the row second number the colum

Comment: you are mixing intput from the console and from function arguments. A simple way to solve the problem is to remove the `move` argument from your function and just read the next line from the console inside the for-loop and extract the two ints from that.

Comment: Would be an option to read them and put them in a matrix?

Comment: That's also possible. Your matrix would be an array of array of int, i.e. `int[][]`. Create it befor the loop as `int[][] moves = new int[n][];` and add each move with `moves[i] = new int[] {a, b};` You'll want your loop to count upwards for this.